# Gooole maps iframe does not appear in an HTML page

Tags: html, google-maps

I want to display a Google Map in my website via iframe, but it does not work. How can I get it done?
Here is source:

```
 <div class="google-map">
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rruga+Azem+Galica,+Tirana,+Albania/@41.3673698,19.7668261,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x135032024ea626ad:0x2af6740dbcc9fac7?hl=en-US"
frameborder="0" width="100%" height="300" marginwidth="0"
marginheight="0" scrolling="no">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The link you used in the src tag is not the embedding link, it's the sharing link.

Use this:

```
<iframe 
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2994.3090479975776!2d19.7668261!3d41.367369800000006!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x135032024ea626ad%3A0x2af6740dbcc9fac7!2sRruga+Azem+Galica%2C+Tirana%2C+Albania!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1427117877944"
    frameborder="0" 
    width="100%" 
    height="300" 
    marginwidth="0"
    marginheight="0" 
    scrolling="no">
</iframe
```